# connecting react native to express

Tags: react-native, express, expo

I have just started with React-Native. I m using expo and express. 
I m trying to connect the front to the back and a GET request.
I get a :

> 'RootErrorBondary':Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError().

In that method,return 
a state update to display an error message or fallbackUI.

thank you!

This is my App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'react-native-axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      greetings: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/v1').then(function (response) {
      const greetings = response.data;
      this.setState({ greetings });
      console.log(greetings);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{greatings}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not display array directly in Text component. You to map it.

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          this.state.greetings.map((item, index) => (
            <Text key={index.toString()}>{item}</Text>
          ))
        };
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Or you can just stringfy and display it with Text component :

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.greetings)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Note that state variable only can access by `this.state`. You cannot directly access `greeting`.

Comment: Thank you Kishan, I tried both suggestions but I still get the same error. :(